# How to generate error_log file

Tags: php, debugging, error-logging, error-log

I am having two servers, both are hosted on hostgator. On one server (which is my own), my php code works as expected, while on another (which is of my client), the code doesn't work properly. Now my server generates `error_log` file, so it's easier to debug. But I can't find the same `error_log` file on my client's server.
Is there anything I can do to generate error_log file. I've already seen answers on other posts and checked the settings in `php.ini` file.

Comment: Or if you can list out the necessary steps to generate the file, I can check which one is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your other server may have error log turned off, so you can do the following.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); //to set the level of errors to log, E_ALL sets all warning, info , error

ini_set("log_errors", true);
ini_set("error_log", "/your_error_path/file.log"); //send error log to log file specified here.
```

Add the above code to your file and then execute in the other server.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check the software version. Then, you could try diffing the two files (php.ini) .

Comment: Actually in my server there's no php.ini file. I just checked.